# print the 2nd highest value containing column name by R

Tags: r

I have input file

```
c = structure(c(10, 22, 40, 20, 25, 22, 15, 10, 45, 8, 13, 59), .Dim = 3:4)
     [1] [2] [3] [4]
     10  20  15   8
     22  25  10   13
     40  22  45   59
```

and I want to get the output like this 
where ever 2nd highest value is present it should print that column name to the row

```
[]
3
1
3
```

I'm able to extract 2nd highest value by

```
apply(c, 1, function(i) sort(i)[ dim(c)[2]-1])
```

but I want to get the column name instead of values.

Comment: you can always use index() with the found value to return the position of your value in the row. Should do what you want (if you add 1)

Comment: can  u tell me exactly code line to how to use index()

Comment: Which package are you using? here "apply" and "dim" are not known. However in standard python lists: [10, 20, 15, 8].index(15) => 2

Comment: so ok but it should do it automatically coz i have 1000 of like this so how to create it

Comment: Don't forget to take into account that values may not be unique.  You can't just take the second to last sorted value because it may be the same as the last sorted value (i.e. the max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
> apply(c, 1, order)[3, ]
[1] 3 1 3
>
```

or if you have more than 4 columns `apply(c, 1, order)[ncol(c)-1, ]`.

By the way it's better not to name variables using names of existing functions such as `c`.

Comment: @Kapil Works for me. I added more concrete example data to your question. Next time, you should do that, so we're sure we're all looking at the same thing.